# Open Source .NET Application Projects (not framework or tool projects) with lots of NUnit Tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, web-applications, nunit

I would like to get a list some reference or sample application projects in .NET/C#- with good test coverage.

The thing is, I want to see this in action for a true application project with any business logic in it. Instead of frameworks with tests in them... like ASP.NET MVC ,Automapper etc. which are no doubt useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.ohloh.net/p/nunit/stacks — check for users who contributes to some project. Some examples:

[CruiseControl.net](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET)

[Witty](http://code.google.com/p/wittytwitter/source/browse/) twitter client

[octalforty-wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/source/browse/)